# Matillion Grid Variable not getting updated through updateGridVariable

Tags: python, matillion

I have a GridVariable defined at the job (using Manage Grid Variables).  I then have a python code which creates a dataframe.  I then append the contents of the dataframe to an array then update my grid variable.  However when I use the grid variable for a transformation job the contents are not updated.

This a snippet of my code

```
for obj in objs:
  s3file=s3_client.get_object(Bucket = 'somebucket', Key = obj.key)
  tbl = pd.read_csv(s3file['Body'])
  row_count=len(tbl.index)
  for i in range(row_count) :
    record=[]
    record.append(tbl.at[i, 'a'])
    record.append(tbl.at[i, 'b'])
    record.append(tbl.at[i, 'c'])
    record.append(tbl.at[i, 'd'])
    record.append(tbl.at[i, 'e'])
    record.append(tbl.at[i, 'f'])
    record.append(tbl.at[i, 'g'])
    record.append(tbl.at[i, 'h'])
    record.append(tbl.at[i, 'i'])
    record.append(tbl.at[i, 'j'])
    record.append(tbl.at[i, 'k'])
    record.append(tbl.at[i, 'l'])
    record.append(tbl.at[i, 'm'])
    record.append(tbl.at[i, 'n'])
    record.append(tbl.at[i, 'o'])
    record.append(tbl.at[i, 'p'])
    record.append(tbl.at[i, 'q'])
    record.append(tbl.at[i, 'r'])
    record.append(tbl.at[i, 's'])
    record.append(tbl.at[i, 't'])
    record.append(tbl.at[i, 'u'])
    record.append(tbl.at[i, 'v'])
    record.append(tbl.at[i, 'w'])
    record.append(tbl.at[i, 'x'])
    record.append(tbl.at[i, 'y'])
    record.append('something')
    array.append(record)
context.updateGridVariable('somegridvar', array)
print(len(array))
arr2=context.getGridVariable('somegridvar')
print(len(arr2))
print(arr2)
```

the print(len(arr2)) line prints the correct number of records
print(arr2) prints the array correctly.

But when I use the grid variable in a transformation it doesn't get the records loaded in the python script.

Answer (score 0):

Looks good so far.. in the Orchestration Job, you have got the Grid Variable to contain the values you need.

Check how you are passing the Grid Variable into the Transformation Job?

The best way is to follow the Python Script component with a Run Transformation, and use the Set Grid Variables property to map somegridvar onto whatever you named the columns in the Transformation Job's own Grid Variable.

You have to do that from the *same* instance of the Orchestration Job run. If you run the Orchestration Job on its own, then sometime later run the Transformation Job on its own, all variables will just have reverted back to their default values.